# Typescript: Ensure a function returns all the possible values of an enum?

Tags: typescript

The following example and comment will explain everything:

```
enum Animal {
  CAT = 'Cat',
  DOG = 'Dog',
  DUCK = 'Duck'
}

// here, I'd like to enforce my function return type to make sure
// it handles all the cases of the enum but as you can see, even if
// we're missing a line to return based on some condition `Animal.DOG`
// we don't get any error from TS
function getRandomAnimalType(): Animal {
  if (1 === 1) {
    return Animal.CAT
  }

  return Animal.DUCK
}
```

So far, the only workaround I've found is to remove the explicit return type on the function and add below:

```
type AssertNever<T extends never> = true
type A = Exclude<Animal,ReturnType<typeof getRandomAnimalType> >;
type B = AssertNever<A>;
```

If I do not return under some conditions all the types, then I get a compilation error on `B`. But that's obviously far from ideal.

Here's a live demo on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbKBvAsAKClAwjACpQC8UA5PkgC4UA0OeAIgPIDiZlzA9gOYMmUZgFV8AaS4VmYAMYBrCjgC%20OHAHp1UABbAATsHpQAkhQAmUFPHnAoNHlFAAzHntm2IATyhOwIWTTwPCBQBjRgeiE0ngAOtvZQyDZQAM4RwBpa8DQ6SCBmKMApUKhoNLpQskgpRVA8TnYVoJBQAEZgOdVQnjxglXmpwIaOAG6gUPBOmVAA7sAUBonwKSnwIHwllmvxDmERIa3VwBbBqTwQtrLBZtlBIQAGcIioAHRs7PfTc1BmwRQ5fGAnRA3n0elcPnB0CIAGUcL5-IFToCaAAlPK-CBPZAoIixYAACgAlBghJMoASAIxkUjkSkkrC4PChIH7WAIHEvQhEISqbBCPaRdnPFBvMTiFRqbDROKwFb6GgAOWAYz0AB4SMAAB40UBmYogFX6AB8XBoejAGWl%20NgXAAolrZCgwGZgGrsah6KjWZE8XE1TLgPUoCj0flzh7cfjTcaANw4QNQABCXBg8r0SqN6pgcaAA).

Is there any better way of achieving what I want here?

Comment: There's no way to require that a function returns every possible of its return type, and normally such a requirement would be quite burdensome.  Any solution I can envisage would involve not annotating the return type and making some other compile time check that the inferred return type is what you think it is.  Is your solution "obviously far from ideal" because it involves three extra type functions?  You could reduce it to one like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKkqGW) but ultimately you will need to do something like it.

Comment: Overall, this seems the thing that a test would be good for, rather than static analysis. I don't think a function should be required to operate within the whole of its codomain. Imagine if you define a `type Str2Num = (x: string): number` function interface that is to be reused. Requiring every instance returns *every single number* seems excessive.

Comment: Well, I didn't go for a test because the function is super trivial (it's a map from a string to an enum) and it'd be easy to forget about updating the test